# Derivative of sign function with two variables in the argument

Tags: derivatives, absolute-value, dirac-delta

It is known that the derivative of the sign function $\mathbf{sgn}$, defined as

$$
\mathrm{sgn}(x) = \frac{x}{|x|}
$$

is given as

$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\mathrm{sgn}(x) = 2\delta (x)
$$

where $\delta(x)$ represents the Dirac delta function. Suppose now I have a sign function with 2 variables $x$, $y$ in its argument. Namely: $\mathrm{sgn}(x-y)$. How can I compute

$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}\mathrm{sgn}(x-y)\qquad?
$$

Comment: The answer is $-2\delta(x-y)$ as it's the usual derivative formula for the composition, what bothers you ?

Comment: @Tuvasbien I blanked out for a moment. I see it now after reworking through the calculations again. Thanks.

Comment: Note that $\text{sgn}(x)=2H(x)-1$.  Therefore, we can see that in distribution $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\text{sgn}(x-y)=2\frac{\partial H(x-y)}{\partial y}=2\delta(x-y)$.

Comment: This formula is not true for $x\not\in\Bbb R$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way to compute it. We have for $\phi \in C^{\infty}_0$

$$\left<\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\text{sgn}(x-y),\phi\right> = -\left<\text{sgn}(x-y),\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\phi\right>$$
$$ = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{sgn}(x-y)\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}dy$$
$$ = -\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}dy + \int_{x}^\infty \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}dy$$
$$ = -2\phi(x).$$

Therefore, in the sense of distributions, we have that $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\text{sgn}(x-y) = -2\delta(x-y)$.

Comment: you deserve it. such a nice approach.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell if it's because I had a long day, but I'm quite unhappy that I couldn't evaluate something so trivial. I figured it out immediately after I posted the question. Here's my approach:

Let $\zeta=x-y$, then

$$
\frac{d}{dy}sgn(x-y) = \frac{d}{dy}sgn(\zeta)=\left(\frac{d}{d\zeta}sgn(\zeta)\right)\frac{d\zeta}{dy}=-2\delta(\zeta)=-2\delta(x-y)
$$

Comment: The chain rule...